# Write synchronously to the command line inside a foreach with a pipelined command

Tags: powershell, powercli

I have the following code:

```
Get-ResourcePool -Server 1.1.1.1 | Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'XX*'} | foreach {
    Write-Host $_.Name -ForegroundColor Red
    Get-ResourcePool -Name $_.Name | Get-VM
}
```

Which is executed asynchronously, due to pipeline - so all of the Write-Host outputs appear on the console and only after that I get the result from Get-ResourcePool.

**Question**: how do I make it synchronous - how do I wait for the pipeline to finish before executing the next foreach cycle.

P.S. I was able to determine that the problem is with the pipeline because when I remove the pipe inside the for each I get what I expect.

P.P.S i tried `Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Get-ResourcePool -Name $Input | Get-VM } -InputObject "$_.Name"` and then wait for the job to finish - but that does not work due to fact that I need to be connected to the vCenter while this command runs, so I get:

```
7/1/2019 6:37:49 PM Get-ResourcePool        You are not currently connected to any servers. Please connect first using a Connect cmdlet.    
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Get-ResourcePool], ViServerConnectionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Core_BaseCmdlet_NotConnectedError,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.GetResourcePool
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

**ADDENDUM**:
Adding screenshots with some of the suggestions - unfortunately none of them work:
[image]

Suggestion from reddit also does not work: https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/8hvjyn/output_delay/

[image]

Adding a pause at the end:
[image]

Adding pause and Out-Host at the end:
[image]

Comment: you are seeing the `output stream to host delay` that was added in psv3. [*sigh ...*] any time you mix direct and indirect output to the screen, the indirect output is delayed [for ~300 ms] to allow PoSh to group things that are "similar". the usual fix is to **_[A]_** do not DO that [mixing direct host output & indirect output stream output] ... or ... **_[B]_** use one of the `-Host` cmdlets to force direct output. ///// i suspect that you can add `Out-Host` to whatever line you want to add to the immediate _host_ display.

Comment: write-output instead of write-host?  write-host 6>&1?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following what you're saying. If I copy your code, minus the server parameter, I'm not seeing the same output. Example: 

```
PS /Users/kruddy> Get-ResourcePool | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike 'Resources'} | foreach { >>     Write-Host $_.Name -ForegroundColor Red
>>     Get-ResourcePool -Name $_.Name | Get-VM
>> }
Development

Name                 PowerState Num CPUs MemoryGB
----                 ---------- -------- --------
aaaaaa           PoweredOff 4        7.859
Management
zzzzzzz          PoweredOn  4        16.000
```

Comment: Will try the `Out-Host` latter today and let you know!

Comment: @KyleRuddy - I'm saying that all `Write-Host $_.Name -ForegroundColor Red` commands in the `foreach` are executed (or at least I see the ouput of those commands) before any of the `Get-ResourcePool -Name $_.Name | Get-VM` commands are executed (or output of those is visible). If you are not seeing the same maybe our powershell versions are different (as per above comment)? Mine is `5.1.17134`

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - added a screenshot of how it works for me. Let me know if you have other ideas on how to accomplish the same.

Comment: that LOOKS like the standard delayed output stream problem. [*frown*] what happens if you add a `pause` just after the `Get-ResourcePool -Name $_.Name | Get-VM` line?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Works exactly the same (if I understood yo correctly). Please see the screenshots.

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius - now, try adding `| Out-Host` after the `| Get-VM` to see if it is the output stream delay or something else ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - same result, added screenshot (Out-Host and Out-Default gave the same result)

Comment: Figured it out - it was my own mistake.

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius - arg ... i have done that more than once ... [*blush*] thank you for clearing that up! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue: it was my personal mistake. I was testing with resource pools where the only resource pool having any VMs was the last one. After I changed it to resource pool containing multiple VMs and tested it, I was able to see it working fine.

Answer (score 1):

> how do I wait for the pipeline to finish before executing the next foreach cycle.

You can force synchronous output to the host application with `Out-Default`:

```
Get-ResourcePool -Server 1.1.1.1 | Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'XX*'} | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.Name -ForegroundColor Red
    Get-ResourcePool -Name $_.Name | Get-VM | Out-Default
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it works the same way - fist all the names are printed, then their information:
https://pastebin.com/raw/gSgAmbrM